# How To Extract (Multidimension) Array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

My Array consist:

```
Array ( 
      [**Anconia**] => Array ( [1335372330] => 7 [1335190784] => 7 [1334883979] => 7 [1334672871] => 7 [1334539093] => 7 [1334337930] => 7 [1334189033] => 7 [1334007668] => 7 [1333567097] => 7 [1332973327] => 7 [1332533799] => 7 [1332215655] => 7 [1331697329] => 7 [1331239651] => 7 [1331075294] => 7 [1330983800] => 7 [1330658201] => 7 [1330484662] => 7 [1330202828] => 7 [1330028992] => 7 ) 
      [**Angellica**] => Array ( [1335372330] => 9 [1335190784] => 9 [1334883979] => 10 [1334539093] => 10 [1334337930] => 10 [1334189033] => 10 [1334007668] => 10 [1331697329] => 9 [1331239651] => 9 [1331075294] => 9 [1330983800] => 9 [1330658201] => 10 [1330484662] => 10 [1330202828] => 8 [1330028992] => 9 )
)

TimeStamp    Tally Number
[1335372330] => 7
```

Using foreach confused me when attempting to extract this.  Want to print the NAME (print in bold) once and display the timestamp = how many.

How would I go about that?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

my attempt

```
foreach($results as $k => $v) { 
   $THEAD .= "<th scope='col'>".$k."</th>"; 
   $TBODY .= "<tr><th scope='row'>".$v."</th>"; 
   $TBODY2 .= "<td>".$results[$k]."</td>"; 
}
```

Comment: foreach($results as $k => $v){
     $THEAD .= "<th scope='col'>".$k."</th>";
     $TBODY .= "<tr><th scope='row'>".$v."</th>";
     $TBODY2 .= "<td>".$results[$k]."</td>";
    }

those are what I basically tried but keep giving me $array as a result

Comment: see above for "timestamp and tally number"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can loop through a nested array the same way as you loop through a single-level array. Example:

```
$myArray = array(
    'first-level-first-key' => array(
        'second-level-first-key' => 'some value',
        'second-level-second-key' => 'another value'
    ),
    'first-level-second-key' => array(
        'seond-level-another-key' => 'yet another value'
    )
);

foreach($myArray as $first_level_key => $first_level_value) {
    echo 'Key: '. $first_level_key .'<br />';
    echo 'Values: ';
    foreach($first_level_value as $second_level_key => $second_level_value) {
        echo $second_level_value .', ';
    }
    echo '<br /><br />';
}
```

This will print out:

```
Key: first-level-first-key
Values: some value, another value,

Key: first-level-second-key
Values: yet another value,
```

Now you know how to loop through nested arrays. Have fun!

**Edit**

A little bit more explanation, as an answer to tmyie's comment below:
As you can see every element is an array in itself:

```
$myArray['first-level-first-key'] = array('second-level-first-key' => ... );
```

The first foreach loops through all the 'first-level' arrays (in my example the elements with key 'first-level-....'). So within that loop, the variable `$first_level_value` holds an array. The second foreach loops through *that*, second-level, array. This nesting of loops is virtually endless if you have saved yet another array in that second level element.

Compare it with having a couple of boxes in front of you. With the first loop, you say 'Open up every box in front of me'. Then for *every single box* you have opened, the nested loop says 'Open up every box I found in that box', and so on.

Although there is most probably something very wrong with your application design if you'd write this, the following example is completely valid:

```
foreach($myArray as $x) {
    foreach($x as $y) {
        foreach($y as $z) {
            foreach($z as $p) {
                // etc
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: EXCELLENT explaination, now I can get a clear picture what to look for :)  Many thanks!

Comment: How come the second loop is necessary? How does it know to stop after the first array (or is that default behaviour)?

Answer (score 1):

Since `$v` is another array in your `foreach`, you need to do another `foreach`:

```
foreach($results as $k => $v) {
   foreach($v as $timestamp => $tally) {
      // do whatever you want
   }
}
```

I'm not giving you a complete code and would prefer to leave that as an exercise for you, but that's how - as per your question - to extract multidimensional array

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
<?php 

echo '<table>';
echo '  <tr>';
echo '    <th>Time Stamp</th>';
echo '    <th>Tally </th>';
echo '  </tr>';

    foreach($myArray as $timeStampArray) 
    {
       foreach($timeStampArray as $timestamp => $tally) 
       {

          echo '  <tr>';
          echo '    <td>'.$timestamp .'</td>';
          echo '    <td>'.$tally.' </td>';
          echo '  </tr>';
       }
    }
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: That works except missing "person's name" but managed to do that on my own, thanks for the information :)